# Can a member function (as opposed to the entire class) befriend a function/class?

Tags: c++, friend

Function F can be declared a friend of class C, so that it can access private and protected members of that entire class.

But is there a way to allow F access only to a particular member function of C, as opposed to allowing F access to the entire class?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986798/subtle-c-inheritance-error-with-protected-fields) is why I want to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly with friendship, but you can achieve a similar effect with a modification of tag-based dispatching:

```
class C
{
public:
  class AccessTag
  {
    friend class C;
    friend void F();
  private:
    AccessTag() {}
  };

  void functionToAccess(AccessTag)
  {
    std::cout << "Restricted function called!\n";
  }
};

void F()
{
  C c;
  c.functionToAccess(C::AccessTag()); // OK
}

void nonF()
{
  C c;
  c.functionToAccess(C::AccessTag()); // error, nonF cannot access ctor of C::AccesTag
}
```

The idea is to only allow `functionToAccess` to be called by those who can construct a `C::AccessTag` object. And because of its private constructor, `C::AccessTag` can only be constructed by its friends. These are `C` (so that it can call `functionToAccess` itself, as it could any other of its private functions), and `F`. `F` cannot access any other non-public members of `C`, because it is not a friend of `C`.

You can even have different access tags for different member functions (or groups of member functions).

Comment: You don't need `C` to be a friend in this example, since it does not create an `AccessTag` on its own. If needed, it could even copy tag objects, since copy operations are implicitly public in `AccessTag`.  In addition you can also make the `AccessTag` a (public) member class of `C`, because it is not really a separate entity but belongs to `C`

Comment: @ArneMertz I added `C` as a friend simply to keep the default behaviour "a class can call its private functions." But good point about making it a nested class, will amend.

Answer (score 5):

No you can't.

One workaround would be to put that particular member function in a separate class C2, from which C inherits, and set up the friendship with C2.

Comment: Or C2 could provide a wrapper interface to certain things in C, so you don't have to set up an artificial inheritance hierarchy.